# run python from Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: python, dynamics-crm

I know i can access a Dynamics instance from a python script by using the oData API, but what about the other way around? Is it possible to somehow call a python script from within Dynamics and possible even pass arguments?

Would this require me to use custom js/c#/other code within Dynamics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to nativley execute a python script within Dynamics.

I would approach this by placing the Python script in a service that can be called via a web service call from Dynamics. You could make the call from form JavaScript or a Plugin using C#.

Comment: This is pretty much what i thought, and the approach i expected to take if directly calling python was not an option. Thank you.